# google drive api v3 How to listen for the closing event of the login pop-up window

Tags: google-drive-api

```
componentDidMount () {
const { SCOPES,CLIENT_ID } = this.googleScrent()
async function initializePicker() {
  await gapi.client.load('https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest');
}
window.gapi && window.gapi.load('client:picker', initializePicker);
if(window.google) {
  window._tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    scope: SCOPES,
    redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
    response_type: "code",
    access_type: 'offline',
    callback: '', // defined later
  })
} else this.setState({noLinkGoogle:true})
```

}

I want to do some actions by listening for the closing event of the Google login pop-up window, but I did not find any related events in the Google documents. Did I miss any actions? Thank you for your help。